# which version of yolo should i choose for my laptop?

Tags: tensorflow, yolo, darknet

So I have a laptop that has **GTX1050ti** and the cpu is **i7 7700hq** and I'm very curious about which version should I choose so it can fit the performance of my laptop and also can **YOLO** predict image or just real-time detection?

Comment: Might be a good thing to raise on the github repo. Appears they don't have any system requirements listed.